# Who handles the program "flow of control" within MVC?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

I have been looking for over a month for a solid answer to this question.  There are only loose "opinions" and no solid facts about how a program's flow of control takes place within a project that is using the MVC design pattern.

I've seen both opinions that yes, the Controller takes care of everything that the Model and View doesn't, and no, the Controller is only responsible for handling the integrity of input and calls to the Model for data manipulation, and that if you use the Controller to handle the "flow of control" then you've designed your program poorly.

I think I'm looking for experience wisdom here.  I don't have any professional programming friends to ask and I'm just learning MVC for the first time.  So your years of experience here will be extremely valuable to me as this kind of information isn't in the documentation/books I have been reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVC Design Pattern has clearly defined roles when it describes the “separation of concerns” within the structure of the program, but the implementation and interaction between those concerns is ambiguous and can therefore interpreted in many different ways.

As a result, most people seem to design their application in a way that gives full "Application Control" to the MVC Controller because it has the name "Controller" even though it’s considered poor form, by some, to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start your research here (https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/)? Take a look at the 'Web Presentation Patterns'. AFAIK, Fowler was the first to catalog/document these patterns, so it seems like a good place to obtain an implementation-agnostic understanding of what the pattern(s)'s objectives are and archetypal implementations.

Bear in mind that each subsequent implementation of the pattern(s) will have its own 'flavour' and interpretation of them.

Comment: Obviously, the PoEAA book has a lot more detail than the website.

Comment: OK, I just read the MVC portion of this book and it only says, "The Application Controller is not the same as the MVC Controller as they are entirely different beasts" (paraphrasing).  But there is no further elaboration on it.  It's basically the same as everything else I've read.  It's stated as an opinion with no solid facts on why.  However, if this is true, then 90% of the code and examples that people are learning from are totally useless as they are giving the MVC Controller "Application Control".

Comment: Reviewing here (https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/applicationController.html), I don't have the book to hand, I think there's reasonable elaboration on their differences. I think there's also an acceptable level of reasoning on when you might introduce the pattern: '...as an application gets more complex this can lead to duplicated code as several controllers for different screens need to know what to do in a certain situation...' So I suppose it boils down to how complex your flow of control is, the amount of code you dedicate to managing that and how much noise it introduces.